# PostgreSQL: union of several tables using dynamic names

Tags: sql, postgresql, information-schema

I have a set of tables (about 100) in schema named `qgep` and which names start with `vl_`.
They have all the same columns (colA, colB, colC).

**What I'd like to do is to get one big table which is the union of all my `vl_*` tables, with also a column with the name of the original table.**

I could get the list of the tables:

```
SELECT table_name
  FROM information_schema.tables 
  WHERE table_schema = 'qgep' 
  AND table_name LIKE 'vl_%'
```

The only way I found to solve my problem is to generate a SQL command to execute it further:

```
SELECT
  string_agg(
    'SELECT '''
    ||table_name
    ||''' AS table_name, colA, colB, colC FROM qgep.'
    ||table_name
  , ' UNION ')::text 
FROM information_schema.tables 
  WHERE table_schema = 'qgep' 
  AND table_name LIKE 'vl_%'"
```

Then executing this SQL command will output what I want. Although, it is very not performant, and quite ugly...

I would like to avoid using `EXECUTE`.
Do you have any advice what to look for?
Is there something I could do using `WITH ... UNION ALL`?

**Would inheritance help me? Is it possible to know from which class is the record in the `select`?**

Comment: `They have all the same columns (colA, colB, colC).` Add a column `col_X` to all of them, all with a different value, and combine the tables into one big table.

Comment: dynamic sql works with execute only (or in shell script :)

Comment: I am using this in a script. Anyway, I was hoping to find a nicer way. And maybe learn a bit.

Comment: Why do you have 100 tables you want to query all at once?

Comment: each table lists possible options for value list (selection combobox), and options are listed in several languages. I would like to generate one big table to use as a dicitonary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was indeed to use inheritance, and I finally found the solution on the [Postgres doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-inherit.html).

```
SELECT p.relname, vl.* 
FROM qgep.is_value_list_base vl, pg_class p 
WHERE vl.tableoid = p.oid;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
create or replace function uall() returns table ( code integer ,
  value character varying(50),
  active boolean,tablename text ) AS $$ 
declare
  _i int;
  _r record;
  _t text := '';
begin 
  select distinct string_agg($s$select *,'$s$||table_name||$s$' from $s$||table_name,' union all ') into _t from information_schema.tables where table_name like 'vl_%';
return query execute _t;
end;$$ language plpgsql
;

select * from uall()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I wanted to avoid using execute. I finally found the solution using inheritance.