# How to select values from a table, whose name is derived from another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called *folder* that stores the name of others tables (named *fileXXX*, where X is a digit), having the same structure, in the same Postgres DB.

I want to build up a SQL statement that retrieve the name of all the *fileXXX* tables in the DB from the *folder* table and create a single SQL Statement with this structure

```
SELECT * FROM _file001_
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM _file002_
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM _file003_
 ...
```

I've found a lot of example on how to use SELECT statements in the WHERE clause, but none for using one in the FROM clause, in such this way.

Comment: share sample input and output

Comment: take a look at cursors

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to write a function for that ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29169573/3984221))

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9aceaa9301d933e7227ef3ed2b7ddade)

1. Query all table names from information schema:

   ```
   SELECT table_name 
   FROM information_schema.tables 
   WHERE table_name LIKE 'file%'
   ```
2. Instead of `SELECT table_name` write include table name into query string

   ```
   SELECT 
       'SELECT * FROM ' || table_name
   ...
   ```
3. Group every result row with `string_agg`, use `UNION ALL` as delimiter:

   ```
   SELECT
       string_agg(/*see (2)*/, ' UNION ALL ')
   ...
   ```
4. This results in your query you mentioned in the question.
5. Last this string can be interpreted as real query and can be executed within this function:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE function union_all() returns table (ids int) AS $$ 
   declare
       _t text := '';
   begin 
       SELECT 
           string_agg('SELECT * FROM ' || table_name, ' UNION ALL ') 
               into _t 
       FROM information_schema.tables 
       WHERE table_name LIKE 'file%';

       return query execute _t;
   end;$$ language plpgsql;
   ```
6. call this function:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM union_all()
   ```